# Custom tokens disappear after closing Ethereum Wallet

Tags: wallets, tokens, ico

I'm on Ethereum Wallet 0.9.0 and I need to add the ICO token addresses every time I restart the wallet. The custom token(s) don't get saved after I exit the wallet. How do I solve this?

Comment: 0.9.0. is the latest version of Ethereum Wallet available on the Ethereum project website. Not too sure what you're referring to.

Comment: My bad, I had multiple tabs open and I was just reading someone had an issue with MyEtherWallet. I'm tired `:(` Can you link me to the ethereum wallet you're talking about? I'm finding a lot of referencing for such a generic term.

Comment: Ethereum-Wallet-installer-0-9-0.exe from https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases

Comment: So I take it there is no solution and any custom token has to be added to the "watch token" list every time I open the wallet?

Comment: I have the same issue, and its getting really annoying

Answer (score 1):

If you add the token address in the watch token under contract tab, You don't need to add it every time after restarting it.

Comment: This is exactly what I did, and need to do again every time I restart the wallet. Because if I don't, they do not show up.

Comment: Surely that's not working as intended?